# Azure Powershell: Delete files in multiple containers

Tags: powershell, azure

I been running this script for each container removing my SQL backups that are older than 35 days. Can anyone assist me on writing a loop (foreach) to go through each container removing files older than 35 days?

Here is my script for one container but I will need to run this for each container.

```
$SubScriptionName = "subname"
$StorageAccountName = "storagename"
Select-AzureSubscription –SubscriptionName $SubScriptionName
Set-AzureSubscription –SubscriptionName $SubScriptionName –CurrentStorageAccount $StorageAccountName

$Container = "nameOfContainer"
$CleanupOlderThan35Days = [DateTime]::UtcNow.AddDays(-35)

Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container  $Container | Where-Object { $_.LastModified.UtcDateTime -lt $CleanupOlderThan35Days } |Remove-AzureStorageBlob
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an Azure Runbook available in the script center that will do this for you.

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Remove-Storage-Blobs-that-aae4b761

You can run this from an Azure Automation Account as a Runbook (my preference) or you could extract out the PowerShell you need to complete your local script implementation.